# Is the cross product in spaces of higher dimensions useful in this way?

Tags: vectors, cross-product

Looking at the Stack Exchange question "[Four dimensional cross product of THREE vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3022394/four-dimensional-cross-product-of-three-vectors)" I sense that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ I can define a cross product between $n-1$ vectors that gives a vector orthogonal to them. A first question: how I transform $|\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B}|=|\mathbf{A}| |\mathbf{B}| \sin \theta$ in this context? But what really matters: can I exploit this extension of cross product to find the $n$-volume "generated" by $n$ linear independent vectors calculating $\mathbf{V}_1\cdot(\mathbf{V}_2 \times \mathbf{V}_3 \times \dots \times \mathbf{V}_n)$? And given a $\left\{ \mathbf{E}_i \right\}$ basis in $\mathbb{R}^4$, can I find its dual by calculating $\mathbf{E}^1 = \frac{ \mathbf{E}_2 \times \mathbf{E}_3 \times \mathbf{E}_4 }{\mathbf{E}_1\cdot( \mathbf{E}_2 \times \mathbf{E}_3 \times \mathbf{E}_4)}$ and so on? This could be exploited to show that in rectilinear (but in general not uniform and not orthogonal) coordinates, both covariant and contravariant basis vectors are everywhere constants.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Multilinear_algebra